# ADFS 3.0 IP Filter

Tags: regex, office365, adfs, adfs3.0

I'm working on a custom claim to match one of two specific IP addresses, and then deny the claim if it's either of them.

Here's the regex (IP changed for fun to 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8)

```
c:[Type == "(notabletoposturl)ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip", Value =~ "(^1\.2\.3\.4|^5\.6\.7\.8)"] => issue(Type = "(notabletoposturl)ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/deny", Value = "DenyUsersWithClaim");
```

It doesn't seem to be working as expected.  I'm still seeing bad username and password attempts from those IPs in the event logs like:

> Token validation failed. See inner exception for more details. 
>   Additional Data 
>   Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
>   Token Type: 
>   (notabletopostlink)ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/UserName  
>   Client IP: 
>   1.2.3.4,{Exchange Online Server IP} 
>   Error message: 
>   username@contoso.com-The user name or password is incorrect

Is my syntax or regex off for ADFS 3?

Comment: remove the (notableposturl) and replace with an h :) to complete the https

Comment: You can't use ADFS as this type of proxy. You have to authenticate first.